# How to set the value of the axis multiplier in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have to plot values in the range `(0, 32000)`. When I do, I get the following tick labels:

```
0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000
```

but I would like to have the following:

```
0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35
```

with the **axis multiplier** (that small number just below the tick labels) `x 10^3`. I really need `x 10^3`.

I know how to force matplotlib to use an axis multiplier. When I use the following:

```
fmt = ScalarFormatter()
fmt.set_powerlimits((-3, 3))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

or this:

```
pylab.ticklabel_format(axis='x', style='sci', scilimits=(-3, 3),
                       useOffset=False)
```

matplotlib always returns with the axis multiplier `x 10^4`, so I get these ugly tick labels:

```
0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5
```

You will agree that the multiplier `x 10^3` results in a lot nicer tick labels. How do I set `10^3` instead of `10^4`?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703813/how-to-set-the-unit-length-of-axis-in-matplotlib) is similar but does not concern setting a concrete value for the axis multiplier.

Comment: I don't agree that `x 10^3` gives nicer tick labels. The scientific notation convention is strong enough that I prefer it over not-having decimal points.

Answer (score 3):

From the [available tickers](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html), two options are:

1. `EngFormatter()`
2. `FuncFormatter()`

Using `EngFormatter` you get the [SI prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix), and optionally a unit by passing `unit='Hz'` for example.

More generally, you can define your own formatter

```py
scale_factor = 10**3
fmt = mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{0:g}'.format(x/scale_factor))
```

---

Edit: 
You could also sub-class `ScalarFormatter` and override the order of magnitude determination, as in:

```py
class MagnitudeFormatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, exponent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self._fixed_exponent = exponent

    def _set_order_of_magnitude(self):
        if self._fixed_exponent:
            self.orderOfMagnitude = self._fixed_exponent
        else:
            super()._set_order_of_magnitude()
```

Then using  `MagnitudeFormatter(3)` as your formatter. This has the benefit in that it retains the "1e3" axis decoration.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce a fixed multiplier of `m` by setting `scilimits=(m, m)`. E.g., in your case:

```
pylab.ticklabel_format(axis='x', style='sci', scilimits=(3, 3), useOffset=False)
```

Answer (score -2):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but you can specify a list of axis tick titles. For instance instead of plotting every tick from 1-10 you could make a list like `['1', '', '3', '', '5', '', '7', '', '9']` would only show a tick label on every other tick. This means so long as your domain you are plotting over doesn't change you can specify the exact strings you want displayed. If you would like I can post some code where I did this.